# Exported excel file is saving as web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel

When I edit and save a exported Excel file through C# code its saving as web page:

```
static String ISO_Date()
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss");
}

protected void lnkbtnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (grdView.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        logger.logTrace("Exporting branch details to excel", Session["UserID"] == null ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]));
        pBindData(null, true);
        grdView.DataSource = ViewState["DataBind"];
        grdView.DataBind();
        ExportGridView();
        pExportGridToExcel(grdView, "Location_Details_" + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now) + ".xls");
    }
}

private void ExportGridView()
{
    System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    // Render grid view control.
    grdView.RenderControl(htw);

    // Write the rendered content to a file.
    string renderedGridView = sw.ToString();
    string path = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ExportedExcel"].ToString();
    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + "_" + ISO_Date() + "_" + FromDate.Replace("/", "-") + "_" + ToDate.Replace("/", "-") + ".xls", renderedGridView);
}

private void pExportGridToExcel(GridView grdGridView, String fileName)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
    String.Format("attachment;filename={0}", fileName));
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    StringWriter stringWrite = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
    ClearControls(grdView);
    grdGridView.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString().Replace(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&nbsp;"), " "));
    Response.End();
}
```

these are the functions i am using for exporting to excel. its exporting but when i open the same excel and try to save it is saving as web page format

Comment: What is the file extension for the produced file?

Comment: actually its exporting, but when i try to save after modified its saving as web page. format is xls.

Comment: Is it saving as 'xls.' instead of '.xls'?

Comment: no. it is saving as '.xls' only

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code :

```
 Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        //To Export all pages
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        this.BindGrid();

        GridView1.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;
        foreach (TableCell cell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
        {
            cell.BackColor = GridView1.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
        }
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            row.BackColor = Color.White;
            foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (row.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
                {
                    cell.BackColor = GridView1.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor;
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.BackColor = GridView1.RowStyle.BackColor;
                }
                cell.CssClass = "textmode";
            }
        }

        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

        //style to format numbers to string
        string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
        Response.Write(style);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: actually its exporting, but when i try to save after modified its saving as web page.

Comment: whats in filename variable can you share, I guess you need to give it extenstion also like myfilename.xls

Comment: String fileName 
pExportGridToExcel(grdView, "Location_Details_" + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now) + ".xls");

Comment: I think issue is when you convert datetime to string it becomes like 30/05/2015 17:55:24 and its not a valid excel file identifier I think you should  use like this DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMMyyyy")

Comment: i have tried whatever you have explained, but still i am getting the same